# Communication between Controller and Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get a return successful or error message if an email was sent or not, but I am having some trouble doing it.

Controller (Here I have the code to send email)

```
public ActionResult SendForm(string message)
{
    HttpStatusCodeResult result;
    try
    {
        //Read SMTP section from Web.Config.
        SmtpSection smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("email", "email"))
        {
            mm.Subject = "";
            mm.Body = message;
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                //EMAIL CODE
                result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Sent Successfully");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SmtpException)
    {
        result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            "Error awhile sending email");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            "Error occurred");
    }

    return result;
}
```

The html code with the modal window where I will show the message:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="alert-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="special-alert"></div>
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finaly, this is the javascript code where the validations are made:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("SendForm", "Index")',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (data, jqXHR, textStatus) {
        clearAlertModal();
        console.log('data: ' + data + ' jqXHR: ' + jqXHR + ' textStatus: ' + textStatus);
        if (textStatus.status == 200) {
            form.find('textarea').val('');
        }
        modal.find('div.special-alert').html(textStatus.statusText);
        modal.modal('show');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('erro: ' + data + ' jqXHR: ' + jqXHR + ' textStatus: ' + errorThrown);
        clearAlertModal();
        modal.find('div.special-alert').html(errorThrown);
        modal.modal('show');
    }
});
```

This line `modal.find('div.special-alert').html(textStatus.statusText);` is where the message "Sent Successfully" will appear, but it is not. Is that anything left? I can't undestand

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does it enter your success function? Does `textStatus` contain the data you think it does?

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the reply. It enters the controller code and the result id is equal to 200 which is the right `textStatus.Status` ID

Comment: You're missing what I'm asking you. Please look at `textStatus`. Not just `textStatus.status`. Do all the properties look right? You need to narrow down whether this is a problem getting a response back from the server, or whether it's a problem with taking some text and displaying it in your DOM.

Comment: Could I debug cshtml on Visual Studio? @mason

Comment: It's JavaScript. You can debug that in the browser.

Comment: This error displays `TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them`. Does it sound familiar? @mason